# Selecting Different points in 2 different layers

Tags: arcmap, analysis, comparison, point

I'd like to make an analysis on points.

I've 2 layers they have house numbers as an attribute. What i'd like to do is compare these 2 layers and select the different ones.

Geometrically there are average 3 meters difference between 2 layers. First i used select by location on arcmap and i tried to select the points which are in 5 meters radius then inverted the selection.But results are not satisfying. now i am searching for another method.

Do you have any ideas? I don't have any expierence in python or something else. I want to do that analyis with ArcMap tools.

Comment: You want to find the points that are close to each other and does not have the same house number?

Comment: yes this is what i want to do.

Answer (score 1):

I used NEAR tool on A set with near features being B set. After that used highlighted fields to join table B to A. Picture shows rows with not the same attribute:

[image]

Solution assumes that NEAR tool picks relevant point from B set.